# TF2.x Custom loss function, numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to use a custom loss function.  I'm now using TF 2.x where eager execution is turned on by default.  I gave this a go with TF 1.x, but ran into too many problems. Is there any alternative to wrapping my function with tf.py_function()?  If not, how would I wrap this?

**General purpose**:  Autoencoder with a custom loss function built around unusual ranked differences. For now I'm just using scipy stats rankdata, but that will change in the future.

**Tensor shape**:  *n, x, x, 1*

*n* images, each of dim *x, x*.
Therefore, I want to run this custom loss function on each pair of *orig, pred* for all *n* images.

**General algorithm:**

```
import scipy.stats as ss
def rank_loss(orig, pred):
    orig_arr = orig.numpy()  # want x,x,1
    pred_arr = pred.numpy()
    orig_rank = (ss.rankdata(orig_arr))  # returns flat array of length size of array
    pred_rank = (ss.rankdata(pred_arr))
    distance_diff = 0
    for i in range(len(orig_rank)): # gets sum of rank differences
        distance_diff = abs(orig_rank[i] - pred_rank[i])
    return distance_diff
```

If I can't do this, am I limited to the available `tf.<funcs>` or how can I pull out the tensor as some form of an array so I can run comparison computations across the two tensors?

I also looked at `tf.make_ndarray`, but that doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: Please note that even if you found a way to do this via Tensorflow, ranking functions (generally, anything discrete) are not differentiable so you will get `None` gradients for your loss

Comment: Right, that's what I was worried about.  I was planning to use MAE or MSE and ideally weight by rank difference in some form, but I wasn't sure it was still usable.  Thanks.